# How to read data from a Response object with cakephp 4

Tags: cakephp, httpresponse, cakephp-4.x

I need to read some data from a http URL with contains this data:

```json
{"result":[{"reg":408,"val":670,"mod":5}]}
```

I've done this in my Controller:

```php
public function param()
{
    $http = new Client();
    $response = $http->get('my https');
    $json = $response->getJson();
    $this->set("json", "$json");
}
```

And in my php file:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Here the data</title>
</head>
<body>
     <td><?php  echo $json; ?></td>
</body>
</html>
```

But I receive the error:

> Array to string conversion

in my Controller for the `$this->set("json", "$json");`.
And in the php, it returns `Array`.
Why?
How can I return the values?

Answer (score 0):

`getJson()` doesn't return the raw JSON, but the *decoded* JSON data, so it could be an array, a string, a number, a boolean, or `null`.

If you want to pass the raw JSON data of the response, then you should use `getStringBody()` instead.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Html Client > Response Objects](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html#namespace-Cake%5CHttp%5CClient)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I used the `getBodyString()` method as you suggested and now it returns the following result: `{"result":[]}`.
How can I access to the element `val`?
@ndm

Comment: @aliciaali Now that sounds like you want to do the opposite of what your code implies. Do you have experience with how PHP works, what arrays and how they're accessed (no offense meant, serious question)?

Comment: Yes, I think to know it. Maybe I didn’t explain myself well before! I need to access the "val" element of the data structure that returns the URL, but any data manipulation I do, always gives me error. The method getBodyString() returns me the empty data, non all the values. I don't know if I could explain myself @ndm

Comment: @aliciaali Well, then you'd need to use `getJson()` to obtain the decoded data. For the initial example you could access `val` like `$json['result'][0]['val']` (use `debug()` to inspect the structure of `$json` after decoding), and if you want to pass the decoded data down to the view, you'd pass it directly, ie you do not put quotes around it, as that would try to convert the array into a string, which won't work, just like echoing an array doesn't work as again this would try to convert it to a string.

Comment: I tried to do in this way but it doesn’t work. After the `get->http`, I've done `$json = $response->getJson();` and then `debug($json);`. The output is: 

    ['result'=>[],]

And if I try to access to `$json['result'][0]['val']`, the output is: 

    undefined array key 0 @ndm

Comment: @aliciaali Well, of course, the result is empty, so that's the expected behavior. You'll have to figure what's possibly wrong with your request that leads to that empty response.